# How can config squid to use a socks as parent or cascade?

Tags: proxy, squid, socks

I have a socks server and a squid linux server.

How can config squid to use socks (as parent or proxy chain or cascade) ?

Answer (score 1):

Squid does not implement socks. You need to run an intermediate proxy server which can talk to both squid and your socks server such as privoxy.

When done, you can configure squid to use privoxy as parent using a line like:

```
cache_peer 127.0.0.1       parent    8118  0  no-query default
```

where `8118` is privoxy port assuming it is running the on same host.

You may need also to play with `never_direct` and `always_direct` configuration parameters of squid.